# Crear input mostrando si es correcto o incorrecto

Tags: php, javascript, entrada

mi proyecto actual consta de una sección en la que a través de un javascript (preferiblemente), haya que escribir en un input una palabra. Seguidamente, se podría saber si es la palabra correcta o no lo es, luego sería incorrecta.

He estado barajando todas las posibilidades, y a lo único que he llegado por el momento es a este código que generaría lo que estoy buscando, pero en un prompt (algo parecido a un popup).

```js
 function checkAnswer(){
    prompt('Cuál es la capital de francia?')
    if('paris'){
        alert('Correcto')
    }
    else{
        alert('Incorrecto. La respuesta correcta sería París')
    }

}
```

```html
<p>Cuál es la capital de Francia </p>

<button onclick="checkAnswer()">Ir a la pregunta</button>
```

Sin embargo, además de que no me funciona, no es lo que necesito, ya que lo necesito para que se genere en la propia página php.

Sabrías por un casual qué función puedo usar? o si tiene algún nombre en concreto lo que estoy buscando?

Muchas gracias y un saludo a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he entendido muy bien lo que necesitas, pero he hecho este ejemplo a ver si te sirve.

He editado la parte de condición.

```js
function validarRespuesta() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[name="respuesta"]');
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  var value =  input.value;
  resultado.innerText = value == 'paris' || value == 'parís' ? 'Correcto' : 'Incorrecto';
}
```

```html
<p>¿Cuál el la capital de Francia?</p>
<input placeholder="Introduce la respuesta" name="respuesta"/>
<button onClick="validarRespuesta()">Validar respuesta</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Thakur! Es exactamente esto lo que estaba intentando conseguir. Siento no haberme explicado bien, pero me has leído la mente a la perfección. Y solamente tengo otra dudilla. Existiría alguna posibilidad de poner algún *else* en la opción de la respuesta, es decir, algo parecido a resultado.innerText = input.value == 'paris' else 'Paris' else 'París' ? 'Correcto' : 'Incorrecto'; Muchas gracias de nuevo